# Integrating comments from Linkedin posts back into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments, integration, linkedin-api

I have been looking for a good and perfect comment system for my wordpress blogs site. I am sharing my posts on both wordpress site and linkedin site as well. People are commenting on those blogs on both platforms. Blogs are same on both LinkedIn and Wordpress but the comments are different as they are on different platforms. Is there any way where I can merge/view comments from LinkedIn on my website on the respective blog page?

Tried few wordpress plugins

Requirement is:

1. Blog A is posted on Wordpress and has comments 1,2 and 3
2. Blogs A is shared on Linkedin and has comments 4 and 5

Expected Result is:

Blog A on Wordpress should display 1,2,3,4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

You can check with linked [Social Media Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve_multiple_total). This might solve your problem. What you need to do is to write some custom code to achieve the functionalities.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. I am trying this out. Aren't there any ready plugins which could achieve this requirement?